# Selenium Python: Invalid Selector in find_element_by_css_selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building a python3 web bot using selenium-webdriver and don't have too much experience with selenium. I am getting an exception, "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified", because of this line of code:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-click='$ctrl.login('gatorlink')']").click();
```

I'm fairly certain it's related to the single quotes surrounding the string "gatorlink", but I am really not sure. I know the selector is not correct. This is the button I am trying to click.

```
<button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="$ctrl.login('gatorlink')" role="menuitem">
<md-icon class="ng-scope material-icons" role="img" aria-label="exit_to_app">exit_to_app</md-icon>
<span class="ng-scope">Log in with GatorLink</span>
</button>
```

It's in a drop down and I am able to open the menu but not click this button at the moment.

Comment: `ng-click` is an attribute of Angular and I doubt it will work like this. Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051164/how-to-click-on-an-angularjs-link-using-python-selenium)?

Comment: I have used ng-click for the other buttons and it has worked just fine - that's why this is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't look carefully earlier but there seems to be a problem with the quotes. Can you try this: `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-click=\"$ctrl.login('gatorlink')\"]").click();`

Comment: @Samarth With that, I get a ElementNotVisibleException. Is this because this button belongs to a dropdown menu? Your code finds the button but it says that it is not "interactable"

Comment: @hodsonus This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @hodsonus: You'll need to open the dropdown menu to click that button in that case. Hope you're doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You have single quotes inside single quotes, it is invalid selector.

You need to escape the single quotes.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-click='$ctrl.login(\\'gatorlink\\')']").click()
```

It works now and finding the element.

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using locator as `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(button.md-button md-ink-ripple).click();`